# Terrafrom custom DSL Warp

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I would like to be able to make a custom DSL that is based on set of ther DSL, to further explain myself I will show the problem:

We have a base DSL that defines a new VPC on AWS, that code it has all the necessary network settings witha all the subnets settings, DMZ style, security groups, etc

Currently we have the base code with all the variables set, so if a team needs to set the new network settings, they will just copy the code, update the `varibales.tf` to their needs.

This works up to the point when I need to update base terraform syntax, it becomes a tedious and error prone to pass those changes accross all the existent networks.

At I woudl like would to make a custom DSL that will wrap all that code, in an example:

```
resource "fancy_aws_network" "network" {
    base_cidr = "172.31.0.0/16"
    use_dmz = True
    subnet_per_az = True
}
```

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you [use terraform modules](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/usage.html)?

Comment: No I did not, is it viable?